# Is it possible to convert wordpress custom post type to normal categories

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

Currently our site's videos are posted as custom post type. We have totally changed the theme and added so many new features. For our new site we are trying to change videos to category. (Custom post type to normal categories). Is this possible. I have exported the custom post type as XML file, but I don't know how to change it to categories.

Comment: You want a custom post type to revert back to the normal default post, with the category 'video' attached to it?

Comment: exactly janw, can you help? Sorry for the delay to respond

Comment: how many post are we taking about? Roughly? It can be done in SQL

Comment: more than 1000 and one more thing, the Video custom post type has 5-6 sub categories.

Comment: Are those sub categories the same type of category the same as the default post category? or is it a lose taxonomy?

Comment: 1000+ posts, currently the structure is Videos and 5 sub categories, all are custom post type. So  I want to change them normal categories, eg: Video custom post type to Video normal category, and video sub categories which is also custom post types to normal sub categories under Videos.

Comment: Are it the same categories as the normal posts? It is doable but the way how differs

Comment: to ask it differently is it a custom taxonomie: http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Comment: yes, current posts is under custom Taxonomies, is it possible exported custom post type data edit with notepad++ instead of SQL edit?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, what you say is possible it is not easy however. I'm advising using SQL. I'll get back to this in the evening. It's too complex to do during office hours. So I'll get back to you in 10-12 hours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally an answer. Before I start These are the conditions I'm using.

- The Custom posttype (called *video*) need to be merged into the default *post*
- Video's has it own custom categories, who needs to be merged into the default categories
- All Video's need to get a category *video*, the old categories need to be children of the newly created *video* category.

Step Zero: **BACKUP my sql BACKUP**

First create a the video category in the default posttype. Note it's ID (it is found in the category edit page in the url under `tag_ID`. I'm assuming ID 4 in my examples

Second we assign this category to the video posttype with the following Sql:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`)
SELECT `ID`, '4' FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'video';
```

Next we assign the existing custom categories as children. You need the video category slug, found on the custom-category page agian in the url with `taxonomy`.

```
UPDATE `wp_term_taxonomy` SET `parent` = 4, `taxonomy` = 'category' WHERE `taxonomy` = 'VIDEO CATEGORYSLUG';
```

The last step is assigning the normal posttype to the custom posttype.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_type` = 'post' WHERE `post_type` = 'video';
```

Now it should be done and everything should be merged. So TEST TEST TEST.
After that the code making the posttype can be disabled.

This should work, if you have questions just ask.

Comment: I havnt looked stackoverflow for past two days, I was searching for a solution, but not found any. Thanks janw for the help. Let me try this tomorrow, I'll update here after checking the solution